# How to limit the number of rows returned for each group

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that stores one record for each item in a filesystem, where an item can be both a folder an an actual file.

```
ID | Name       | Date | Parent ID
-----------------------------------
0  | someFolder | xxx  | NULL
1  | a.txt      | yyy  | 0
2  | b.txt      | zzz  | 0
```

So if I have a folder structure that goes like this:

```
mainFolder (ID = 0)
    folder1
      a.txt
      b.txt
    folder2
      c.txt
      d.txt
```

And I want to find all leaf nodes, 'grouped' by what root folder they're in, I use this query:

```
select id, name, date, connect_by_root name as "Group" from myTable
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
start with parentid = 0
connect by prior id = parentid
```

Which gets me something along the lines of this output:

```
ID | Name  | Date | Group
---------------------------
3  | a.txt | xxx  | folder1
4  | b.txt | yyy  | folder1
8  | c.txt | zzz  | folder2
9  | d.txt | xyz  | folder2
```

What I want to do is limit the number of rows returned for each 'group'. For example, even if both folders had more than 2 items, I would want only the first two (in terms of most recent date) from each. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm attempting to use the row_number() analytic to assign a row number to for each file in a group. starting at 1 going to X  and then use a where clause to limit the row_number to just the 2 files desired...  Since the row_number has to materialize before we can apply a where clause to it, I need to use a subselect or CTE.

Not sure how well a CTE and connect by prior along with a row_number will play together... May have to use 2 CTE's

I doubt I have the syntax perfect without testing; but this convey's a general concept.

1st attempt:

```
With CTE AS (
select id, name, date, connect_by_root name as "Group",
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by connect_by_root name order by ID ) RN
from myTable
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
start with parentid = 0
connect by prior id = parentid)
Select * from cte where RN <= 2
```

Second attempt:

```
With CTE AS (
select id, name, date, connect_by_root name as "Group" from myTable
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
start with parentid = 0
connect by prior id = parentid),

CTE2 as (Select A.*, 
        Row_number() over (partition by Group order by ID) RN from CTE A)
Select * from cte2 where RN <= 2
```

Comment: Both queries ended up working, thanks! (The first one just needed to have `from myTable` moved after `RN`)

Comment: Corrected so it's after RN. Good, I liked the first one better.  But was concerned that the root names may not be available to the analytic at time of execution (order of operation issue)